# How to retrieve my custom attribute to refer a specific style?

Tags: android, attributes

I have a widget with custom attributes, and I want to allow specify the "section" attribute to know the style of a specific part into my component.

```
<declare-styleable name="BulletTextView">
     <attr name="section" value="reference" /> <<<< This one
     <attr name="bulletFormat" />
</declare-styleable>
```

From my component (code), how can I retrieve this attribute value (=style):

```
case R.styleable.BulletTextView_section:
     mSectionStyle = a.getResourceId(attr, NO_ID); <<< which method?
     break;
```

Thank you very much

Comment: `getResourceId()` is the correct method.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the method you want.

Docs here;

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/TypedArray#getResourceId(int,%20int)